# Opacity of gravatars of some users in chat not updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

In the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) I noticed the gravatars not becoming opaque after a while:

[image]

Inspection of the html dom revealed this inside the `<li>` of balpha:

```
<span class="data">
  <span class="last-activity-time">b13dce689732844e6590da37048f0eaf</span>
</span>
```

Not sure why the Gravatar id of balpha is there because for others that same html fragment shows:

```
<span class="data">
    <span class="last-activity-time">1411749249</span>
</span>
```

This is observed on IE11 and confirmed on Firefox and Chrome (dev channel).

<sub>I expect this can be repro-ed by only entering a room but not do any activity as the chat script calls `sidebarActivity` in the enter function with the email_hash but on the activity filter with `now()`.</sub>

Can this be fixed? It makes chat near impossible to use ;-)

Comment: wait, b13dce689732844e6590da37048f0eaf... something familiar...

Comment: I found some result that CreationDate="2010-09-20T17:19:07.117" DisplayName="balpha" EmailHash="b13dce689732844e6590da37048f0eaf"

Comment: Ahh, I remember b13dce689732844e6590da37048f0eaf like it was yesterday...

Comment: @Anna it *was* yesterday. ;)

Comment: Is that why you blurred your gravatar rene? Don't you trust the blurring algorithm any longer?

Comment: I expect that this is part of the moderator conspiracy to keep tabs on us, considering all the people not being blurred have diamonds.

Comment: Obviously, when Bart is not in the Tavern, bugs are happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ooops, nice catch and absolutely correct analysis. Fixed.

Comment: Just FYI: something is off in that same area: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ2zv.png I didn't check if it is the same root-cause.

Comment: It looks like it is related to when SE staff goes through the chat transcript. Basically when you see a blurred avatar  of an SE employee as shown you know you're in for trouble.